# Windows 11: CPU too old and tried AllowUpgradesWithUnsupportedTPMOrCPU

Tags: cpu, windows-11-upgrade

I have a 5 years old computer with an Intel I5-6600k CPU which is too old for upgrading to Windows 11. All other W11 requirements are met (TMP2.0 ...). I read that one can install and run W11 with this regedit entry:

```
Path: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup\MoSetup
Name: AllowUpgradesWithUnsupportedTPMOrCPU
Type: REG_DWORD
Value: 1
```

It was said that the system might not run, and certain W11 update won't work. Has anybody tried it and can report on his experiences?

---

EDIT: I upgraded from W10Pro a month ago now and haven't had any problems so far. It works fine on: I5-6600k with 16 GB Ram and 500 GB M2-SSD. The performance is the same as with Windows 10.

Comment: It’s unsupported by Microsoft.  It’s entirely up to you if you want to install Windows 11 on your device

Comment: It is also unsupported to overclock a CPU and I did it without problems for years. The alternative is to buy a new board and CPU. So I ask the brave to share their experiences.

Comment: It's quite simple. You can upgrade, but the performance may be really bad. We tried it at work with different computers and some are working normaly, other computers are much less performant. Additionally no one can say what microsoft will do with these unsupported versions update wise. Maybe they get just the security updates or you'll have to reinstall windows anytime you want to update it.

Answer (score 10):

I've just upgraded my Gen6 i7-6700 Desktop (with TMP 2.0) to Windows 11 using [the `AllowUpgradesWithUnsupportedTPMOrCPU` workaround](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ways-to-install-windows-11-e0edbbfb-cfc5-4011-868b-2ce77ac7c70e#:%7E:text=AllowUpgradesWithUnsupportedTPMOrCPU) and it's been working perfectly well so far, still a fast, performant machine.

I upgraded in-place by downloading [Win11 ISO](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11), mounting it (with right click) and running `setup.exe`.

If I ever see Windows 11 updates stop flowing, I will consider upgrading or replacing this aging hardware, but otherwise I don't see a good reason for that.

Comment: Thanks, did you upgrade from W10 Home or Pro? If Pro, are you now on Home?

Comment: @musbach From Win 10 Pro ⟶ Win11 Pro. I upgraded in-place by downloading [Win11 Pro ISO](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11), mounting it (with right click) and running `setup.exe`.

Comment: @musbach - Home vs Professional does not matter. Windows 10 Home would upgrade to Windows 11 Home while Windows 10 Professional would upgrade to Windows 11 Professional

Comment: @Ramhound you're right. I was under impression I had to choose the ISO image type, but I just checked and apparently I only had to choose the language.

Comment: @noseratio - Windows 10 Professional and Home ISO have been combined  since November 2015.  There is a conman’s to list which editions are contained within ISO, irrelevant, to this question or answer of course. I fully intend to use this question as a duplicate to any questions about Windows 11 on unsupported configurations.  This answer is good since it’s short and to the point, and confirms, the key works

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft advises against this method (of course):

[Microsoft Windows 11 Upgrade](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ways-to-install-windows-11-e0edbbfb-cfc5-4011-868b-2ce77ac7c70e)

The Verge says the modification might work, but

**"Just know that Microsoft reserves the right to withhold security updates if you go this route"**

Lack of security updates may result in your system being compromised with malware.

[Verge implementation of Mod](https://www.theverge.com/22715331/how-to-install-windows-11-unsupported-cpu-intel-amd-registry-regedit)

Comment: Use an alternative AV?

Comment: Generally Windows Defender is very good at this point. There are also other good AV products out there.

Comment: @Moab - Strictly speaking, I am not sure Microsoft literally said that would happen, they just said it was unsupported.  I don't trust these news articles since the majority of their author typically makes money on "Microsoft did something stupid" article titles. I have heard people have installed the version released on Oct 5 on unsupported hardware and they still received updates this week.

Comment: @Ramhound, I can confirm I've just got [KB5006674](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/october-12-2021-kb5006674-os-build-22000-258-32255bb8-6b25-4265-934c-74fdb25f4d35), a cumulative Windows 11 update.

Comment: @noseratio - Your experience is matching what I am hearing in the larger Window's community

Comment: @Ramhound I think the security update risk will mainly comes from hardware that are not TPM compliant.
If this issue is only the fact that Windows didn't list the CPU, the risk would rather be slower speed for that CPU and/or higher kernel crashes.

Comment: @Togh - Except today there are no Windows security feature that absolutely require TPM other than BitLocker

Comment: @Ramhound If one day such feature is added, then it may block further updates.
So up to now there are no issues, but maybe (maybe not, who knows?) later this feature requirement could stop the update process.

Comment: @Togh - Why exactly was your original comment directed towards me instead anyone else? Your comment had little to do with my comment indicating, it does not appear that cumulative updates are being blocked, on systems where Windows 11 is not official supported due to the processor and/or TPM requirement. *I could careless about security features that don't exist today.*