# How can I update TPM on Windows 10 machine for Windows 11?

Tags: security, bios, tpm, windows-11, windows-11-upgrade

When preparing my 5-years old Intel Core i7 computer for Windows 11, I ran PC Health Check. These are the results:

[image: PC Health Check results]

Regarding TPM, I tried to upgrade it to 2.0. From **Trusted Platform Module (TPM) Management**, I cleared TPM ownership and restarted the computer. Then I run TPM 2.0 update utility which I got from Dell. When the computer was restarting, I saw this message for only a few seconds:

`UPDATE FAILED. BLOCKED BY TPM FW POLICY`

There is nothing promising found on Google search about this. I don't know how to turn off TPM FW Policy, or if FW stands for fireware or something else.

My computer is DELL OptiPlex 7040 with Core i7 3.40GHz processor bought in April 2016.

Comment: Do you understand that, even if you enable TPM 2.0, that your processor won't be supported by Windows 11? There is absolutely no chance that a machine from 2016 contains a processor that is supported by Windows 11.  There is a registry key you can use, to install Windows 11, on otherwise unsupported hardware. [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/1680925/windows-11-cpu-too-old-and-tried-allowupgradeswithunsupportedtpmorcpu/1681003#comment2582135_1681003) is instructions on that key.

Comment: https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/nl-nl/000126503/trusted-platform-module-tpm-upgrade-downgrade-process-for-windows-7-and-10-operating-system-upgrade-downgrade?lang=en states that you need to update the bios firmware before you can upgrade TPM to 2.0. That said Ramhound is correct, that your CPU is most likely not going to be supported.

Comment: While my suggestion is just install Windows 11 without even bothering with TPM 2.0.  What is the output of [`Disable-TpmAutoProvisioning`](https://blog.arnonerba.com/2019/05/dell-tpm-1-2-to-2-0-upgrade-instructions)? The reason I suggest just enabling key to bypass the requirement, your CPU will not be supported regardless, so you will still have to enable it because of the CPU. Be sure you update your firmware before you run the utility after you disable TPM Auto Provisioning. It also appears you have installed Windows 10 while in Legacy mode which means MBR which Windows 11 does NOT support.

Comment: @Ramhound The verdict on this isn't final yet. Some 2016 Core-I CPU's (and a few late 2015 Xeons) are probably going to be supported (not initially, but maybe later), if the UEFI can apply Intels microcode patches against Spectre/Meltdown vulnerabilites. My employer has high-level contacts in Redmond and we asked because we have about 100.000 of these machines worldwide. We haven't decided if (or when) we will go to Win11, but we want to know our options.  Microsoft is very vague about this and refuses to make a definitive statement on this at the moment.

Comment: @Tonny - I think you are thinking of 7th generation Intel Core products might be supported.  According to my research, DELL OptiPlex 7040, has a 6th generation core processor.  Of course the author didn't provide that information in their question.  *What verdict isn't final by the way?*  The Intel microcode is applied each time Windows is booted. It does not resolve the underline with permanent microcode, that would require a firmware update, but you already know that.

Comment: @Ramhound I was thinking of 7th Gen indeed. I didn't check the actual CPU for this Optiplex model.  And I missed the April 2016 reference. The 7th Gen is from 2016 but only started to come available to the OEMs as of April. So a computer on the shelves in April would almost be guaranteed to use the previous generation.

Answer (score 2):

According to Dell's own instructions:

A) Make sure you are on the latest UEFI Bios version.
B) Clear the TPM completely (from within UEFI).
C) Try the TPM upgrade patch again.

You probably skipped either A) or B).